# How are return results computed in a recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion, return

I thought up to this point in time, that I understood how a return works, but once I got into the recursions, I suppose I'm a bit more lost than the originally thought.

Suppose, I have a function for count, that how many times a char pops up in a string.

```
int frequency(char ch, string input, int pos) {
   if (pos == inputString.length()) {
      return 0;
   }

   if (inputString[pos] == ch) {
      return 1 + frequency(ch, inputString, pos + 1);
   }
   else {
      return frequency(ch, inputString, pos+1);
   }
}
```

If I were to pass to it, the string "Jeff" and looking for "f", it returns a value of `2`.

**So, how does it know when to stop?**

- Does `return 0` end any method with return type `int`?
- And if so, why does it still return the value of `2`, when the *final* return says return `0`?

Comment: What if `pos > inputString.length()` is true?

Comment: Then it would just return 0? Obviously, when I call the method I pass the pos parameter a 0. A string can't hold a length value of -1, can it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last return

```
return 0;
```

is only the last time the function is called during the recursion. This is needed to stop the recursion at some point. For the call before this last one one of the other return statements is executed, e.g:

```
return 1 + frequency(ch, inputString, pos + 1);
```

Thus the 0 is added up to the 1 and any previous results of the recursion.

PS:
As long as the function return statement calls the function again the recursion continues. Only when the return simply returns something (without calling the fucntion again) the recursion stops.

Here is a more simple example that calculates the sum of all integers up to N:

```
int calcSum(int N){

    if ( N == 1 ) return 1;          // recursion stops here

    return N + calcSum( N-1 );       // otherwise continue to add up 

}
```

Multiple return statements in one function are not special to recursion. The function just returns on the first return it encounters.

Comment: How does the recursion know that it's finished when the 0 is called? Any method I have encountered thus far ends with a return method, however this one has multiple returns. Do methods with an int return type end when the value 0 is returned?

Also, returns in recursions are additive? Can they be multiplicative or divisive as well?

Comment: _"How does the recursion know that it's finished when the 0 is called?"_ That's done in the body of the 1st `if()` statement. It simply returns, without adding another recursive call.

Comment: @tobi303 Aaaah. I didn't really think of it that way. The return 0 effectively comes outside of the recursion. The recursion only takes place as long as it's not equal to strlen. Once it is equal to it, it returns 0, causing it to not keep going in the recursion. The stacks then finish their thang, get down to the base case, and then 0 is added to whatever was returned within the recursion.

Comment: @JeffreyDilley yes, take my example, the final sum for eg `calcSum(3)` you only get when the call to `calcSum(3)` finally returns, but to do so the recursion first has to stop which happens at the call `calcSum(1)`. Only when the function is not called again the stack will be unwinded

Comment: @JeffreyDilley May be my answer, which tries to break down what's happening, helps to make that behavior clearer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ definitely a better explanation while my answer could need an edit ...i am just too lazy at the moment ;)

Answer (score 2):

> **So, how does it know when to stop?**

When no more recursive calls are added from a particular branch in the recursively called function it will stop, and the call stack will be cleared with returning values in the reverse order of the calls were issued ([LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(C%2B%2B))). That's done here:

```
if (pos == inputString.length()) {
    return 0;
}
```

Any of the other branches call the function recursively and take a step down in the call stack:

```
if (inputString[pos] == ch) {
    return 1 + frequency(ch, inputString, pos + 1);
            // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
}
else {
    return frequency(ch, inputString, pos+1);
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
}
```

> - Does `return 0;` end any method with return type int?

Yes, and it will do for any return types that can be initialized with `0`

> - And if so, why does it still return the value of `2`, when the final return says return `0`?

Because the results of the recursive call results were accumulated on the stack:

```
   return 1 + frequency(ch, inputString, pos + 1);
//          ^ the result of the operation will be saved on the stack when the call returns
```

... and you see the final result of the (first) recursive call in your driver function.

---

BTW, the much cheaper implementation by means of performance and memory usage would be a simple loop. There aren't any drawbacks regarding the linear time behavior anyway:

```
int frequency(char ch, string input) {
   int result = 0;
   for(int pos = 0; pos < input.size(); ++pos) {
        if (input[pos] == ch) {
           ++result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of a recursive calls as a stack of function calls. At some point it may hit `return 0;` This mean that one of the function calls on the stack is completed. Thus an element on the stack is popped. The function's *final* return happens when the stack is empty.

Comment: So then yes, a return 0 effectively "pops" a stack, which is what ends it?

Comment: @JeffreyDilley _"which is what ends it?"_ When the stack is empty, no more popping can be done.